# Merge column from command output into a single row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am using `dnf list installed` to list all installed packages, which returns the following output:

```
zenity.x86_64                                                                         3.22.0-1.fc25                                                               @@commandline          
zip.x86_64                                                                            3.0-16.fc24                                                                 @@commandline          
zlib.i686                                                                             1.2.8-10.fc24                                                               @@commandline          
zlib.x86_64                                                                           1.2.8-10.fc24                                                               @@commandline          
zlib-devel.x86_64                                                                     1.2.8-10.fc24                                                               @@commandline          
znc.x86_64                                                                            1.6.5-1.fc25                                                                @@commandline
```

I am only interested in names of the packages, i.e. the value of the first column but only until the `.` (e.g. `znc.x86_64` -> `znc`).

How could I merge results from this command output into a single line separated with spaces (e.g. `zip zlib zlib-devel znc`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** + ***sort*** solution:

```
dnf list installed | awk -F. -v ORS="\0" '{print $1" "}' | sort -zu && echo ""
```

The output should look like:

```
zenity zip zlib zlib-devel znc
```

---

`-v ORS="\0"` - considering input as zero-terminated records

`sort -zu` - to get *unique* zero-terminated values